# Comparing an array/string and its permutations to a dictionary

Tags: php, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary txt file that contains over 11k records of food ingredients, separated by new lines.
Currently I am mapping the whole dictionary into an array, where the KEYS are the ingredients.

```
$file = file('file.txt',  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
$arr = Array();
foreach($file as $key) {
        $arr[$key] = 1;
}
```

I receive as input a recipe line, for example:

> 2 sticks (16 tablespoons) unsalted butter, room temperature mixed with 2 tbsp olive oil

Currently what I am doing is removing the quantity(2), removing the measurement type(sticks), commas and anything inside brackets.

I am left with:

> unsalted butter room temperature mixed with olive oil

I need to be able to get unsalted butter and olive oil back from the string as quickly as possible.

My initial thought was to create all possible permutations of the string and do a simple `array_key_exists/isset/==` check on the array to see if it is a valid word.

But once I get into such large strings, there are just way too many possible permutations for me to handle.

Is there an elegant solution to the problem?
I could brute force it and just compare each line in the dictionary to the recipe line via strpos for example, but I do not think this is the right way to go.
The only thing I could come up, but is also limiting me quite a bit is to limit the amount of permutations returned.
So for example if I have 10 words, but I allow only combination of 3 words, which gets me to around 720 results if I have done my math correctly.

Comment: You read and parse that file into memory for _each_ single request? That will give a huge load and terrible performance. Consider using a database instead of a file! This also should solve your dilemma with the huge set of permutations, since you can make use of operators when querying the database.

Comment: I am saving the final array via APC, so no, I do not parse it every time. I forgot to add that to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the search results for subsets of words as a graph where a subset of words has an edge to a superset of words with one extra word if the superset is also a valid set, and if you store all the one extra words pointing out of a subset node as a hashtable, and words in subsets are stored from lexicographically smallest to largest in the word-combination graph, then you can do breadth-first search on this graph and determine the largest number of words that your query string contains, much quicker than checking all subsets of words of the desired minimum length and larger.